# nginx forward to localhost 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, nginx

I have nginx as proxy to api (localhost:5000). I want forward request on port 555 to localhost 5000. I'm using docker for nginx and api application.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context:  ./server/xxx.Api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    network_mode: host

  proxy:
    build:
      context:  ./server/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "555:555"
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 555;
  server_name localhost;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
    proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
    proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
    proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
    proxy_read_timeout 1800;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
  }
}
```

But instead of application in 5000 port I'm having 502 Bad Gateway from nginx. Application is also in docker.

If I forward request to another website

```
proxy_pass http://reddit.com;
```

everything works. What is wrong here?

Comment: your containers dont share network

Comment: That was that, sorry I forgot to put comment.

Comment: Keep in mind `127.0.0.1` inside a container is not the same as 127.0.0.1 on your host machine. Run `docker network ls` and review your network settings.